# svg grunticon, css fill color

Tags: css, svg, gruntjs

I'm using grunticon to add svg's.

Everything working but I'm struggling to style the svg's with css.

I simple want to chnage the fill color of the svg.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">

        <head>  
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />

            <!--jQuery-->
            <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

            <!--css-->
            <style type="text/css">

                .icon-heart{
                    background: red;
                }

                .icon-heart{
                    fill: red;
                }   

            </style>

            <title>Title of the document</title>

            <script>
                /* grunticon Stylesheet Loader | https://github.com/filamentgroup/grunticon | (c) 2012 Scott Jehl, Filament Group, Inc. | MIT license. */
    window.grunticon=function(e){if(e&&3===e.length){var t=window,n=!(!t.document.createElementNS||!t.document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg","svg").createSVGRect||!document.implementation.hasFeature("http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/feature#Image","1.1")||window.opera&&-1===navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Chrome")),o=function(o){var r=t.document.createElement("link"),a=t.document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];r.rel="stylesheet",r.href=e[o&&n?0:o?1:2],a.parentNode.insertBefore(r,a)},r=new t.Image;r.onerror=function(){o(!1)},r.onload=function(){o(1===r.width&&1===r.height)},r.src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///ywAAAAAAQABAAACAUwAOw=="}};
                grunticon(["images/output/icons.data.svg.css", "images/output/icons.data.png.css", "images/output/icons.fallback.css"]);
            </script>

            <noscript><link href="icons.fallback.css" rel="stylesheet"></noscript>

        </head>

    <body>

        <div class="icon-heart-1" style="height: 50px; width: 50px;"></div>
        <div class="icon-heart" style="height: 50px; width: 50px;"></div>

    </body>

    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure that the svg's you are using do not have the fill="{color}" or style="fill:{color}" hardcoded in them as these will override any css style you apply.

I think you will have to do this by manually updating the svg unless there is a grunt way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

To change the style attributes via css, you need to embed the svg into the dom. Grunticon (above v2.0) offers a easy way to do this.
You need to enable the enhanceSVG option in your gruntfile and then you can use the data-grunticon-embed attribute on your div to embed it.
Look at their documentation for more information
https://github.com/filamentgroup/grunticon#version-20-is-out---heres-whats-new